# Nouveau driver does not detect external monitors on laptop

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, nouveau

Laptop is an Alienware M18 R2 (dual GTX675M) which is working with dual external monitors when using the Nvidia 390 (latest) driver.

The driver is old and lately current versions of Ubuntu 22.04 appear to have introduced instabilities with the old driver.  The issue is inability to play video at any resolution without a 50%+ dropped frame rate.

Due to issues with the old GTX675M (mobile) card and the Nvidia 390 driver I decided to try the nouveau driver to see if any of my issues would resolve.

Using the nouveau driver the video dropped frame issue is now corrected.

However after changing the driver in the "additional drivers" tab and rebooting I can only see the built in laptop display.  Any external monitor (HDMI, DP) is not detected.

Out from inxi

```
$ inxi -GSayz
System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic
    root=UUID=a8c6ea47-b7ab-4fb9-bee1-c24ec2a2f958 ro quiet splash
    vt.handoff=7
  Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 vt: 7
    dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] vendor: Dell driver: nvidia
    v: 390.157 alternate: nvidiafb,nouveau,nvidia_drm pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1212
    class-ID: 0300
  Device-2: NVIDIA GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] vendor: Dell driver: nvidia
    v: 390.157 alternate: nvidiafb,nouveau,nvidia_drm pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16 bus-ID: 07:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1212
    class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: marco v: 1.26.0 driver:
    X: loaded: nouveau,vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting gpu: nvidia,nvidia
    display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 1920x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 508x286mm (20.0x11.3")
    s-diag: 583mm (23")
  Monitor-1: default res: 1920x1080 hz: 77 size: N/A
  OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 15.0.7 256 bits)
    v: 4.5 Mesa 23.0.4-0ubuntu1~22.04.1 direct render: Yes
```

And xrandr:

```
$ xrandr -q
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

and:

```
lspci | grep VGA
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] (rev a1)
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] (rev a1)
```

Is this a limitation of the nouveau driver or should I expect to see the external monitors?

Addition:

So I reinstalled the nVidia 390.157 drivers and all monitors can be detected agin.

```
inxi -GSayz

System:
  Kernel: 6.2.0-36-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A
    parameters: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-36-generic
    root=UUID=a8c6ea47-b7ab-4fb9-bee1-c24ec2a2f958 ro quiet splash
    vt.handoff=7
  Desktop: MATE 1.26.0 info: mate-panel wm: marco 1.26.0 vt: 7
    dm: LightDM 1.30.0 Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Graphics:
  Device-1: NVIDIA GF114M [GeForce GTX 675M] vendor: Dell driver: nvidia
    v: 390.157 alternate: nvidiafb,nouveau,nvidia_drm pcie: gen: 2 speed: 5 GT/s
    lanes: 8 link-max: lanes: 16 bus-ID: 01:00.0 chip-ID: 10de:1212
    class-ID: 0300
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 compositor: marco v: 1.26.0 driver:
    X: loaded: nvidia unloaded: fbdev,modesetting,nouveau,vesa gpu: nvidia
    display-ID: :0.0 screens: 1
  Screen-1: 0 s-res: 3840x1080 s-dpi: 96 s-size: 1016x286mm (40.0x11.3")
    s-diag: 1055mm (41.6")
  Monitor-1: DP-0 pos: primary,left res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 70
    size: 697x392mm (27.4x15.4") diag: 800mm (31.5")
  Monitor-2: HDMI-0 pos: right res: 1920x1080 hz: 60 dpi: 92
    size: 531x299mm (20.9x11.8") diag: 609mm (24")
  OpenGL: renderer: GeForce GTX 675M/PCIe/SSE2 v: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 390.157
    direct render: Yes
```

So I am not sure why the nouveau driver doesn't want to see the monitors.

In the process my video performance issue has somehow been resolved.

So no need to go back to the nouveau drivers.

Comment: The nouveau driver should be perfectly capable of using external monitors, personally I never use Nvidia drivers and never had an issue. The laptop I am on now has 2 external monitors connected, one via HDMI and one via DP. So maybe a hardware/BIOS setting issue perhaps. I suggest you update your question with the exact make/model of your laptop as well as state exactly how your monitor/s are connected. e.g. what sort of port on laptop and what sort of port on monitor. Direct cable connection or going via any sort of adaptor or dock?